# Appsmith AWS Dynamo Plugin query

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, appsmith

Anyone here using Appsmith open source here: https://github.com/appsmithorg/appsmith

I have an issue with DynamoDb Plugin.
If anyone worked with Dynamodb in Appsmith, can you guys please show me a simple query that I can put into appsmith query editor and run it correctly? Cause they don't have documents yet.

I saw the DynamoDB Documents in AWS, but don't know how to write it in Appsmith.
Thank guys.

Answer (score 6):

Update:

The documentation change has been merged and it is now available at: https://docs.appsmith.com/datasource-reference/querying-dynamodb

--

A pull request has been raised to add the documentation for DynamoDB plugin. If everything goes well, it should be available in a week or so. I will update after the pull request has been merged. After the merge it will be available on [Appsmith's documentation site](https://docs.appsmith.com/).

Appsmith also has a very active [Discord channel](https://discord.com/invite/rBTTVJp) where you can ask questions and get resolution super fast. Apart from this please feel free to initiate a [Github discussion](https://github.com/appsmithorg/appsmith/discussions) or send an email to support@appsmith.com

Comment: It's available now!